# Improving bad fit for data using Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, parameter-estimation

I am trying to fit some data to estimate model parameters in a system of 5 ODEs. I cannot get a good fit.
First I tried using Matlab `lsqcurvefit` and I get a very poor fit. [image]
Then I tried `fmincon` and this is the code that I used,

```
    close all
clear
initial= [1.8;0.55;8.5*10^-12;0.095;0.25;10^6;0.35];

t=[0.509283106;1.564581803;2.607620249;3.6594436;4.706343542;5.708739739;6.695689949;8.810390184;9.867523091;...
    10.86417531;11.92179091;12.93253759;13.97605872;];

data=[3.288981289;4.875259875;4.613305613;5.675675676;5.995841996;6.607068607;4.88981289;5.180873181;0.043659044...
    ;3.288981289;5.224532225;3.594594595;3.405405405;];

lb=[1,0.2,10^-13,0.001,0.001,10^5,0.001];
ub=[100,100,inf,20,20,10^9,20];

x=[t,data];
[fit,fval]=fmincon(@(parameters)ssq(parameters,x),initial,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
figure
scatter(t,data,5,'r')
hold on

time=0:14;
fittedValues=model(fit',time);
plot(time,fittedValues,'g')
legend('data','fit')

function SSE=ssq(parameters,x)
time=x(:,1);
data=x(:,2);

fitted=model(parameters,time);
error=fitted(:,1)-data;
SSE=sum(error.^2);

end

function output= model(parameters,thours)
    x0=[10^3,0.001,0.001,10^-8];
    [time,values] = ode45(@Equations,thours,x0);

function s=Equations(t,y)

a1=0.3368;
p8=0.03;
p2=10^-3;
N=(((2.5+7.5)/2)*10^9)*5;
p8=1/24;
a2=1/11;
k2=10^6/a2;
p5=0.75;
p6=8;
p7=0.15;

s=zeros(4,1);

s(1)=(parameters(4)*y(1))*(1-(y(1)/parameters(6)))-p7*a1*y(1)*(1-(y(3)/k2))-...
    parameters(1)*y(4)*y(1)/(parameters(2)*y(4)+y(1))-p2*y(1)...
    +p5*y(3)+p8*y(2);
s(2)=p8*parameters(1)*y(4)*y(1)/(parameters(2)*y(4)+y(1))-p8*y(2)+...
    parameters(7)*y(2)*(1-(y(2)/(y(4)*p6)));
s(3)=p7*a1*y(1)*(1-(y(3)/k2))-p5*y(3)+parameters(5)*y(3);
s(4)=parameters(3)*(N-y(4))*y(1)-p8*y(4);

end


output=values(:,1)+values(:,2)+values(:,3);
output=log10(output);

end
```

With this code I had to increase the upper bound of 3rd parameter to `inf` as I kept on geting warnings as,  `Derivative finite-differencing step was artificially reduced to be within bound constraints. This may adversely
affect convergence. Increasing distance between bound constraints, in dimension 3, to be at least 1.9983e-08 may improve
results.`
The `fmincon` fit is
[image]

I believe the fits depends highly on what I choose as the initial guesses and the lower and upper bounds. What can I do to get a much better fit?
Because when I changed the model parameters by hand (just arbitrarily changing parameter values and plotting the model output against data) I seem to get get somewhat of a better ft than I am getting using these data fitting options.

So, can someone please point to me what I am doing wrong here and some ideas as to how I can achieve a better fit.

Comment: How to measure the fit? What is your error function? What families of functions are you allowed to search in? Without deciding that it is difficult to answer.

Comment: @mathreadler  I am using a least squares fit. But, any other fitting function that can give a good fit will be ok. By good fit I mean something that will closely match the data than the fit that I am getting at the moment as at the moment the fitted curve does not go anywhere near the data points. At the moment using fmincon the objective function values (sum of squares error of (data-fit)) is 79.

Comment: Least squares fitting a second degree polynomial will probably give a bit better fit. Even better would a sine+cosine + second degree polynomial. You may need to tune the frequency though.

Comment: @mathreadler So with that would it still take into account the ODE system output? Do you mean to change the error function to a second degree polynomial? Because I can't simply fit a second degree polynomial to the data. It has to be the model output results that I fit in. Could you please explain a bit as to how I can use your suggestion in the code? Thank you.

Comment: "By good fit I mean something that will closely match the data than the fit that I am getting at the moment". So you mean anything that will look good on a plot? What looks good on a plot can be very subjective (more of an aesthetical question than a mathematical one) and difficult to formalize.